# GridView in Android-(See full-list)

Tags: android

I am having a String   `Australia@2@India@30@UK@4@USA@43`

I need to show this screen on my activity, using GridView. I am able to view only two entries at the moment,
either

```
USA 43
UK   4
```

OR

```
Australia 2
India     30
```

I need to see the entire list on GridView.

```
 <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

                android:textColor="#151B54" >
            </GridView>
```

Comment: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'numRows' in package 'android'

Comment: try android:numColumns="auto_fit" in gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your xml like this shown below..

```
<GridView  
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

for more example see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) & [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) & [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)